# Where does the Version DWORD come from in the Uninstall Registry Key (Windows Installer)?

Tags: windows-installer

I'm trying to write an custom automatic updater for our app. Its originally installed using InstallShield and MSI. I found the information used for Add / Remove programs is located in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{Guid}

If i update the Version, VersionMajor and VersionMinor to be the same as the new version (when i run the installer) then the patch applies fine, otherwise it does a repair when the app starts.

The VersionMajor and VersionMinor both match the Primary Exe's Major and Minor version. The Version though seems to be a random number and dosn't match any part of the Exe's version. Where does it come from?

For example if the Exe version is 5.12.0.2019

I can run this code to get the Version Info

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileVersionInfo vi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"C:\MyApp.exe");
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", vi.FileVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("Major: {0}", vi.FileMajorPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Minor: {0}", vi.FileMinorPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Build: {0}", vi.FileBuildPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Private: {0}", vi.FilePrivatePart);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Version: {0}", vi.ProductVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Major: {0}", vi.ProductMajorPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Minor: {0}", vi.ProductMinorPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Build: {0}", vi.ProductBuildPart);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Private: {0}", vi.ProductPrivatePart);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Version: 5.12.2019
Major: 5
Minor: 12
Build: 0
Private: 2019
Product Version: 5.12.2019
Product Major: 5
Product Minor: 12
Product Build: 0
Product Private: 2019
```

But the version that is in the reg is some 9digit number like "118358017" that doesn't match any of that info. I was expecting to see the Private version in there but this isn't the case

Comment: I wrote some code to turn this into a System.Version object. Please check out my answer to [How to convert version number present in registry to System.Version?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30607120/2596334)

Answer (score 5):

It may help to look at 118358017 in hexadecimal:

```
070E0001
```

After breaking it apart under the assumption that it's a packed DWORD of Major/minor/Build of MMmmBBBB, this sounds like 7.14.1 to me.