# Convert version number in registry to System.Version?

Tags: c#, .net, registry, version

I'm retrieving a version number from the registry like so:

```
rKey.GetValue("Version")
```

Now I want to convert this to a `System.Version` object.
How do I do this?

Comment: What *format* is that value in? Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's a string...

```
string versionText = (string) rKey.GetValue("Version");
Version version = new Version(versionText);
```

Comment: Most subkeys in the \Uninstall registry key have the Version value is stored as REG_DWORD. Sometimes they are REG_SZ and can use this option directly..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's a REG_DWORD (commonly found as part of Uninstall Registry Keys)...

[According to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this key is "Derived from [ProductVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property".
It describes 3 fields: Major, Minor, and Build.

The DWORD value (in HEX) can be broken up in the following way:

> 0xMMmmBBBB
>   Where MM = the Major version, mm = the Minor version, and BBBB = the Build.

Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to do that:

[image: Action shot]

MainWindow:

```c#
<Window x:Class="RegVersionParse.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:RegVersionParse"
        Height="150" Width="500"
        Title="Uninstall Registry Key ProductVersion Decoder">
    <Window.Resources>
        <l:VersionConverter x:Key="OutConvert"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="10"
            Content="Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
               &#x0a;    Input  REG_DWORD  Version  (as Decimal)"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,15,0,5">
            <Label Content="Input: "/>
            <TextBox MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding MyInputVersion, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Label Content="Output: " Margin="40,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding MyOutput, Converter={StaticResource OutConvert}}" 
                     IsReadOnly="True" Background="{Binding StatusColor}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```c#
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace RegVersionParse
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Version), typeof(string))]
    public class VersionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) { return "Not A Version"; }
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml</summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string myInput;
        public string MyInputVersion
        {
            get { return myInput; }
            set
            {
                if (myInput != value)
                {
                    myInput = value;
                    MyOutput = RegDwordIntegerVersionParse(value);               
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        Version myOutput;
        public Version MyOutput
        {
            get { return myOutput; }
            set { if (myOutput != value) { myOutput = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
        }

        Brush statusColor;
        public Brush StatusColor
        {
            get { return statusColor; }
            set { if (statusColor != value) { statusColor = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            StatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is designed specifically for producing a 
        /// System.Version object from the Uninstall information
        /// ("Version" key) in the Windows registry for a given app.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">Using the Registry class to obtain a 
        /// REG_DWORD value for an installed application, 
        /// Input the integer value as a string.</param>
        /// <returns>System Version Object (Major, Minor, Build) </returns>
        public System.Version RegDwordIntegerVersionParse(string input)
        {
            string HexMajor = string.Empty;
            string HexMinor = string.Empty;
            string HexBuild = string.Empty;
            int Major = -1;
            int Minor = -1;
            int Build = -1;

            try
            {
                //int numVersion = int.Parse(input);
                Int64 numVersion = Int64.Parse(input); 

                string hexVersion = numVersion.ToString("X8");

                // Could also check for alphanumeric...
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexVersion) && hexVersion.Length >= 5)
                {
                    HexMajor = hexVersion.Substring(0, 2);
                    HexMinor = hexVersion.Substring(2, 2);

                    // The Build number could be up to 4 characters, but might be less!
                    HexBuild = hexVersion.Substring(4, hexVersion.Length - 4);

                    Major = int.Parse(HexMajor, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    Minor = int.Parse(HexMinor, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                    Build = int.Parse(HexBuild, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                    StatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    return new Version(Major, Minor, Build);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    StatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                    return new Version();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                StatusColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                return new Version();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming it's a particular kind of version number. All we really know is that the value is in the registry under a key of Version. Given that the OP accepted my answer, I would hope that means it worked. The OP didn't mention uninstallers, as your link refers to.

Comment: @JonSkeet True enough. I started to ask a new question about this, but couldn't find a good reason that it wouldn't be a duplicate of this one. Then I figured out the answer myself and thought I would share.

Comment: It looks like you've been confused by `decimalVersion.ToString("X")` dropping leading zeros, giving you 28-bit integer strings (only seven characters long). This code is actually shifting the version information over by four bits, and then swapping the first and second four bits of the bytes for major and minor. Check what happens for 1.17.0, or 17.1.0. You'd be better off using bit-wise operators (`>>` and `&`) rather than converting to a hex string and shuffling the characters around.

Comment: @mdonoughe Thank you for finding this! You are very correct. Once the Hex value is padded to 8, the problem of bit shifting goes away. Editing my answer now.